# Is it possible to delete related videos when ending a youtube video?

Tags: html, youtube-api

I want to insert a youtube video with HTML, but I want the related youtube videos to not appear. I know that this could be done before from the same platform, I found a way to do it, but what I don't understand is why it works with some videos and not with others?

This is my code, could someone suggest me how to solve it, or if it is possible?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
<iframe width="100%" height="425" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qy81R-VFCjQ?autoplay=&showinfo=0&loop=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**-Parameters-**

YouTube has now changed the `?rel=0` so by assigning it 0 it doesn't get rid of the related videos but instead shows related videos from the channel that that video was played.

As of now there isn't any other parameters that will get rid of the related videos.

**-Possible Fixes-**

1. You can either try using a different video streaming service like Vimeo or DailyMotion.
2. If you're making your website with Wordpress you can get the Embed Plus for Yotube plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/

I hope this helped!

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help.
It's what I read about some YouTube terms, but I don't know why some videos let me remove the ads and others don't.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to remove ads from a video, you could use YouTube premium and download the video and then put the file directly on the site with the <video> element: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp